# How to push view controller onto SLComposeServiceViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-share-extension

This is what I have now:

[image]

but I would prefer sth like this:

[image]

When I tap on the option I push a new `UIViewController` onto the stack:

This is how my `configurationItems()` method looks like:

```
override func configurationItems() -> [AnyObject]! {

    let composeSheet = SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem()
    composeSheet.title = "firstItem"
    composeSheet.value = "defaultValue"

    let composeSecondSheet = SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem()
    composeSecondSheet.title = "secondItem"

    return [composeSheet, composeSecondSheet]
}
```

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

This is what it needs to be done:

```
let composeSheet = SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem()
composeSheet.title = "firstItem"
composeSheet.value = "defaultValue"
composeSheet.tapHandler = {
    self.pushConfigurationViewController(UIViewController())
}
```

Once tap handler is assigned it automatically creates the right arrow:

[image]

When you press that `composeSheet` you push controller onto navigation stack:

[image]

Comment: What if I want to present a full view controller after firstitem clicked.same like dropbox is doing with SAVE TO optiont. I tried "controller.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext"  but not succeed.